# Partial sums and products in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to build an array of partial products of the entries of another array in numpy. So far I have:

```
from numpy.random import dirichlet
from numpy import ones, prod

alpha = ones(100)
p = dirichlet(alpha)
```

I know I can whatever partial product by slicing my array. For example:

```
q = prod(p[0:10])
```

returns the product of the first 10 entries of `p`.

How could I build the array `q` so that entry `i` is the product of the `i-1` previous values of `p`?

I've tried:

```
for i in p:
    q[i+1] = prod(p[0:i-1])
```

however, this throws a numpy.float64 doesn't support item assignment error.

How would I go about building this array? For sums, could I just replace `prod` with `sum`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the NumPy functions `cumprod` and `cumsum`

```
from numpy import cumprod, cumsum
# your code here
q = cumprod(p)
r = cumsum(p)
```

Documentation

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html
- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html

Comment: Yep, didn't see that in the question

Comment: Thanks! I search for 'numpy partial products' but that wasn't returned!

Answer (score 2):

While `cumprod` is a good simple way of doing this, it would be good to understand why you got an error.

```
q = prod(p[0:10])  # q is now a float
for i in p:  
    q[i+1] = prod(p[0:i-1])
```

There are 2 problems with the iteration.  `i` is an item of `p`, not an index.  In fact it probably is a float.  `q[i+1]` does not work because `q` is a float, not an array.

```
q=np.zeros(p.size+1)
for i in range(p.size):
    q[i+1]=np.prod(p[:i])
```

This iteration works.  Now `q` is a large enough array, and `i` is an integer, a valid index.  Where it uses `i`,`i+1` or `i-1` is something you can tweak.